# How do Tables in custom Linq-to-SQL DataContext get instantiated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

If I want to use a Table from a DataContext, I need to instantiate it:

```
Table<Customer> customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();
```

But if it's in a custom DataContext:

```
public partial class Northwind : DataContext
{
    public Table<Customer> Customers;
    ...
}
```

I can just use it like this:

```
Table<Customer> customers = db.Customers;
```

Where is it instantiated?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), it is just a property getter that `return this.GetTable<TEntity>()`

Comment: @penleychan Very nice! You can transform that into an answer. I didn't imagine it would be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.table-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), it is just a property getter that `return this.GetTable<TEntity>()`.

Eg.

```
public partial class DataClasses1DataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext {  
   public System.Data.Linq.Table<User> Users {  
      get {  
         return this.GetTable<User>();  
      }  
   }  
}
```